# How can i render a .obj with .mtl in AR (no unity)?

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, augmented-reality, arcore

I need to render a 3D Object with obj+mtl format, i found lot of samples of ARCore, vuforia, viroCore and some others but for example ARCore sample only takes .obj + .png (texture).

I rendered a 3d object with rajawali in a surface but not in AR. I'm a  bit confused about how to draw a 3d object and render it with this format.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by you "rendered an object with rajawali in a surface but not in AR"? What format is your object in? As a developer on Viro, I can say that Viro (React and Core) support OBJ's and FBX object file formats.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english also I'm learning from zero. What I mean is I only achieve to draw a 3d model but i also need to render it in AR. What I need is load 3d model (obj file + mtl file) from a directory, and render it over a mark. If you can guide me it would be great help @ACVM.

Comment: Hi @Juanjo232, if you use Viro-React, displaying objects are fairly simple: https://docs.viromedia.com/docs/3d-objects#section-materials

Just follow our set-up guide, add your Obj/Materials to `<project>/js/res/` and then refer to it in the `Viro3DObject` component.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Viro React](https://docs.viromedia.com/docs/quick-start) or [ViroCore](https://virocore.viromedia.com/docs/getting-started).

1. Follow the getting started/quick-start guides.
2. Then read our [Viro3DObject](https://docs.viromedia.com/docs/3d-objects#section-materials) guide for Viro React or [3D Object](https://virocore.viromedia.com/docs/3d-objects) guide for ViroCore

If all you want to do is to render your 3D object in AR, then my suggestion would be to use Viro React as it's much quicker to get to seeing an object.